# I keep getting this error when I start my server in Netbeans

Tags: java

I am new to Java and creating databases in Netbeans. I just recently imported the latest version of Java Derby to my Java DB. I keep getting this error when I start my server.

```
*Mon Mar 21 21:33:56 PST 2022 : Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy.

WARNING: A terminally deprecated method in java.lang.System has been called

WARNING: System::setSecurityManager has been called by org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl (file:/C:/Java%20Derby/db-derby-10.15.2.0-bin/lib/derbynet.jar)

WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl

WARNING: System::setSecurityManager will be removed in a future release

Mon Mar 21 21:33:56 PST 2022 : Apache Derby Network Server - 10.15.2.0 - (1873585) started and 
ready to accept connections on port 1527*
```

I'm totally new to everything so any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!!

Comment: Well, the output you posted does not contain any error, it only contains warnings. Warnings are not errors; warnings do not prevent the server from running. In this case they notice the user that something may break in the future. Your log also says *"started and ready to accept connections"*, so it *has* been started successfully.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I see. I'm new with creating databases that's why I was worried if those warnings will cause problems in my database. Thank you for your answer though! It helped me understand. Thank you!